# Forcing $\diamondsuit$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm trying to show that if $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of partial functions $\omega_1\to\omega_1$ with countable domain, and $M$ is a ctm of $ZFC$, then $M[G]\models\diamondsuit$.

I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550835/how-to-force-diamondsuit/551791#551791), asked previously on this site. Now, when constructing the $\beta_n$ and $q_n$, we're stepping out of the ground model $M$, so I don't see why $\langle\beta_n:n<\omega\rangle$ should be bounded in $\omega_1^M$. I know this forcing does not add new bounded sequences of length $\le\omega_1$, but it's not clear to me that the sequence $\langle\beta_n:n<\omega\rangle$ even belongs to $M[G]$.

I have similar doubts regarding using closedness (?) of the forcing to get an extension of all the $q_n$ (since we want $\langle q_n:n<\omega\rangle\in M$), but I'm guessing both things will follow by a similar reasoning.

Comment: Consider proving that the sequence $A_{\alpha}= \{\gamma\in \alpha:( \exists p\in G)(p(\alpha+\gamma)=0)\}$ always witnesses $\diamondsuit$.

Comment: The answer is maybe misleading since it is written "choose a generic $G_n$". But there is no need to choose a whole generic. The choice of $\beta_{n+1}$,$q_{n+1}$ with the required properties can be made entirely inside $M$. The "choose $G_n$" part is only there to argue that such $\beta,q$ exist.